# theos error "Control reaches end of non-void function" cydia tweak

Tags: objective-c, cydia

I am trying to create a cydia tweak which changes some methods in a game

But I am always getting this error

```
control reaches end of non-void function
```

Here are the codes from my Tweak.xm(I shortened them down to where the errors are occurring at)

```
 %hook Player



 -(void)Jump:(int)jump {

        if ((Upgrade = YES)) {

            jump = 1;

            %orig(jump); 

                            }

        else {

            %orig;

             }

    }
    -(int)GetSkill {

        if ((Upgrade = YES)) {

            return 1;

                             }

        else {

            %orig;

             }

    }

    %end

    %hook MainLayer

    -(int)GetSkill:(int)skill {
        if ((Upgrade = YES)) {

            skill = 1;

            %orig(skill);

                             }
        else {

            %orig;


             }

    }

    %end
```

I have no idea why isn't the code block is not working. Sorry about that

Pls help me here, although it is a warning
The codes still seems to change the game even if I click No in the Alert

Comment: The methods do not return a return value in any case. Sometimes the compiler warning is misleading because your code is well structured and always returns a valule. In that case you can overcome the compiler warning just by adding 'return 0;' to the end of the mehtod although this statement may never be executed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your function `-(int)GetSkill:(int)skill`  has a return type of `int` specified yet you dont have a `return` statement. make it a `(void)` if its not meant to return anything

if you have a `return` inside an if statement, there has to be at least 1 return in the `if` and the `else` part for it to be able to return always, if not, it will give you that warning

side note: this statement `if ((Upgrade = YES))` will always be true, since it is assigning `Upgrade` instead of doing a comparison, you probably want to change it to `if ((Upgrade == YES))`

Answer (score 0):

I have no experience with Theos, nor app tweaking.

Having said that, I suggest you use `return %orig;` instead of `%orig;`.